# Oracle SQL - select parts of a string

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select `abcdef.txt` from the following string?

```
abcdef.123.txt
```

I only know how to select abcdef by doing `select substr('abcdef.123.txt',1,6) from dual;`

Comment: is the format *always* fixed?alphabets followed by `.` followed by a number followed by `.` followed by alphabets?

Comment: @vkp yes the format is always fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using || for concat and substr  -3 for right part

```
select substr('abcdef.123.txt',1,6)  || '.' ||substr('abcdef.123.txt',-3) from dual;
```

or avoiding a concat (like suggested by Luc M)

```
select substr('abcdef.123.txt',1,7)   || substr('abcdef.123.txt',-3) from dual;
```

Comment: You could extract the dot to avoid a concatenation.

Comment: @LucM   there are several way for do this  .. i have just proposed one way   and i have update the answer with your suggestion too ..

Answer (score 2):

A general solution, assuming the input string has exactly two periods `.` and you want to extract the first and third tokens, separated by one `.` The length of the "tokens" in the input string can be arbitrary (including zero!) and they can contain any characters other than `.`

```
select regexp_replace('abcde.123.xyz', '([^.]*).([^.]*).([^.]*)', '\1.\3') as result
  from dual;

RESULT
---------
abcde.xyz
```

Explanation:

- `[   ]` means *match any of the characters between brackets*.
- `^`
  means *do NOT match the characters in the brackets*  - so...
- `[^.]`
  means *match any character OTHER THAN `.`*
- `*` means *match zero or
  more occurrences, as many as possible* (**"greedy"** match)
- `( ... )` is called a *subexpression*... see below
- `'\1.\3` means *replace the original string
  with the first subexpression, followed by `.`, followed by the THIRD
  subexpression*.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the substring of anything surrounded by dots (inclusive) with a single dot.  No dependence on lengths of components of the string:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('abcdef.123.txt', '\..*\.', '.') fixed
     from dual;

FIXED
----------
abcdef.txt

SQL>
```